# cleveref: crefname with accentuated initial

Tags: cross-referencing, accents, cleveref

I am French and I would like to change a crefname. The problem is that adding a crefname beginning with an accentuated letter brings an error when using `\Cref` command. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[french]{cleveref}

\crefname{figure}{équation}{équation}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}
  foobar
  \caption{baz}
  \label{qux}
 \end{figure}


 \Cref{qux}

 Équation
\end{document}
```

Uncommenting the line `\crefname{figure}{équation}{équation}` produces the following errors:

```
! Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.20  \Cref{qux}

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \UTFviii@two@octets was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.20  \Cref{qux}


! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20  \Cref{qux}

! Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.20  \Cref{qux}

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \UTFviii@two@octets was complete.
<to be read again> 
                       \par 
l.20  \Cref{qux}


! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20  \Cref{qux}
```

Do you know how I can use cleveref with accentuated initial letters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities: either

```
\crefname{figure}{{é}quation}{{é}quations}
```

or

```
\crefname{figure}{équation}{équations}
\Crefname{figure}{Équation}{Équations}
```

I believe the latter is best.